# Can any projective variety be covered by a single affine variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

This is a reinterpretation of a HW question, so I'm not totally sure if this belongs here, but I was wondering about the following question:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. We define a variety to be a scheme over $k$ that is integral, separated, and finite type, and we say that a variety $X$ is projective if there exists a closed immersion $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}_k^n$ for some $k$. Is it true that for any projective variety $X$, there exists some affine scheme $Y$ and a surjective morphism of $k$-schemes $Y\to X$?

In the original question, we do not require $Y$ to be irreducible (which turns it into a trivial problem), however, I did not see this, and was nonetheless able to prove the theorem in the case where $X=\mathbb{P}_k^n$, without being able to carry my arguments over to a closed subscheme of $X$. In general, I suspect that we would require $\dim Y>\dim X$, as can be seen in the case where $X$ is a nonsingular curve that is not $\mathbb{P}^1$.

My main intuition here is that this problem most likely requires a geometric rather than algebraic solution. More precisely, if we let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be of codimension $d$, then my thinking was that if we could cover $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{*\}$ by an affine, where $*\notin X$, then we could then do some sort of projection, but this is all informal speculation.

Comment: What was your solution for $\mathbb P^n_k$?

Comment: For a much stronger statement than what you're asking for, Google for the "Jouanolou trick".

Comment: In characteristic $\ne2$, just take the usual degree $2$ map from $\mathbb{P}^n$ to itself, and remove the hyperplane $\{x_0+\cdots+x_n=0\}$ from the source, then we still have surjectivity.

In characteristic $2$, we can just consider the degree $3$ map instead.

Comment: I was thinking one could take the cone over the projective space and remove a non linear hyperplane through the origin. So in the case of $\mathbb P^1$, one could take $k[x,y]_{(y-x^2)}$ and the obvious map sending $(x,y) \to [x,y]$. I think this should work in general, no?

Comment: The answer is "yes":  For $\mathbb{P}^n$, note that this is isomorphic to $PGL_{n+1}/P$, where $P$ is the stabilizer of a point; $PGL_{n+1}$ is affine, giving a surjective (quotient) map $PGL_{n+1}\to \mathbb{P}^n$.  Now given $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, one may base change along this map; the result is a closed subvariety of $PGL_{n+1}$ (hence affine) surjecting onto $X$ as desired.

Comment: If you want, you can also do it with $\dim Y= \dim X$. For example for curves, the idea is to take some higher degree cover and remove one point in a smooth fibre (or really any fibre containing more than one point). The covering curve minus the point is affine, and the map is still surjective. You can make this work in higher dimension as well. In fact there exist surjections from $\mathbb A^n$ to $\mathbb P^n$. (But I don't know how to use this method to get $Y \to X$ generically finite with $Y$ *irreducible* in general. For that, Jouanolou's trick is great if $\dim Y$ is allowed to be big.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: To get $Y$ irreducible, one must assume $X$ irreducible; then one can take a smooth affine cover as in my construction and cut it down to the appropriate dimension by taking a sufficiently general collection of equations; this will be irreducible by standard arguments.

Comment: @DanielLitt ah yes, the standard Bertini irreducibility argument should do the trick to get from either Jouanolou's or your version to one in the same dimension. (Note that the OP indeed does assume $X$ to be irreducible.)

Comment: If you can do this for projective space (as @Daniel Litt has shown), you can do this for any projective variety. Let $X\to P$ be a finite map where $P$ is a projective space of dimension same as $X$. Take an affine variety mapping onto $P$ and base change. Finiteness ensures that the base change is affine.